# Question regarding to Climbing Stairs Memoization Top-Down Approach

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

The question is: "You are climbing a staircase. It takes n steps to reach the top.
Each time you can either climb 1 or 2 steps. In how many distinct ways can you climb to the top?"

The code of Top-down memoization approach is:

```
class Solution:
    def climbStairs(self, n: int) -> int:
        def climb(n, memo): #So, here our function will have two values. n is the number of steps and let's call it memo. Memo will be used to show the return value that reduces the recursive calls
            if n < 0: #edge case
                return 0 #Return None
            if n == 0:
                return 1 #There is an error while executing the program and it is not performing what it was intended to do
            if memo.get(n): #if the number of steps n are taken which is from 1 to 45, then we can use the get method to find the number of steps
                return memo[n] #to find the number of recursive calls we will use the memoization method which is
            memo[n] = climb(n-1, memo) + climb(n-2, memo) #memoization will return the number of steps be using the previous two steps
            return memo[n]#return the value that reduces the recursive calls
        return climb(n, {})
```

I am confused with the lines
"

```
if memo.get(n):
return memo[n]
memo[n] = climb(n-1, memo) + climb(n-2, memo)
return memo[n]
```

"
Why are we using two 'return memo[n]'? I thought,
"

```
if memo.get(n):
memo[n] = climb(n-1, memo) + climb(n-2, memo)
return memo[n]
```

" is how the memoization idea depicts here.

Also, please correct me if my comments explaining the code is wrong, because I am new to programming. If there is any other easier and better optimized method that i should implement to solve this question, then please let me know.

I posted some other questions before, and some people answered in a rude tone despite understanding the fact that I am seeing for help here for self teaching myself programming. I understand that their knowledge is very advanced, and I am nowhere near the level. So, I will appreciate it if I can understand the code and learn programming from the people answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first return statement is inside an `if` condition, and it returns a value when it's already computed, in order to not compute 2 or more times the same operation.

```
if memo.get(n): #This if is basically checking if the code has already computed the function in n
 return memo[n]

#This line never executes if the code has already returned memo[n] in the if condition used to NOT compute multiple times the same operation
memo[n] = climb(n-1, memo) + climb(n-2, memo) 
return memo[n]
```

But in the second return statement, it gives the computation of `climb(n-1, memo) + climb(n-2, memo)` that is stored on `memo[n]` and has never been done before in the code execution.

I suggest you to watch these videos to understand more deeply how recursion works:

[Video 1](https://youtu.be/IJDJ0kBx2LM)

[Video 2](https://youtu.be/oBt53YbR9Kk)